# Was my Ubuntu installation successful?

Tags: 12.04

I am a new user of Ubuntu.
I follow all the instructions to install it.
It seemed to be successful. And I had saved some files in it.
Somehow, I don't really see the GRUB menu when I start Ubuntu again.
Still, it shows me the menu of installation/try/defaults.
When I choose default (since I've installed), it enters like normal, but the files that I'd saved earlier are missing. Everything is like "newly-installed", everything is just new.
Does anyone know what happen?

Comment: fyi, i'm using Live USB method.

Comment: If you are able to access BIOS, are you setting your USB to the top-priority in the boot order or booting of it? If you need more help, I can write a more detailed answer. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the USB flash drive is removed from your computer, and reboot. If it boots up, it should be working.